# Print in a web app the content of an url in the client's printer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing, activex

In a local web site we used to have in an HTML page an active-x called client-side (via javascript) that given an url it printed the content of the page in the default printer of the client without showing any message.
Active-x are not supported anymore since IE7 so we have to achieve the same result somehow.
It is important that the print has to be generated via client (no server-side) because we need to get its local printer and without showing any prompt message (automatically get the default printer).
Does anybody know a solution or give a tip?